# fragment lifecycle while navigating between fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-lifecycle

I do understand bit about fragment lifecycle, but I am finding me unable to visualize well the flow chart(or control diagram). When we move from one fragment to other. eg

```
            TheFragment tf6 = new TheFragment(); // TheFragment class extends Fragmet 
            adapter.addFragment(tf6 , naam[q--]);
            tf6.setArguments(args);

            TheFragment tf5 = new TheFragment(); another fragment
            adapter.addFragment(tf5 , naam[q--]);
            tf5.setArguments(args);

           `viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);`
```

Can anyone explain me just a flow of control or diagram in which we move from one fragment to other, so which method of which fragment called in a sequence.(Like OnPouse() of frag1 to onResume() of frag2 (for example)) Thanks in advance for your explanation.

Comment: ViewPager loads multiple Fragments at once

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View pager and fragment lifecycle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697951/view-pager-and-fragment-lifecycle)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355127/android-lifecycle-management-of-fragments-within-viewpager-and-fragmentpageradap

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by creating a fragment class and overriding all its methods with a log. Just navigate and see which log appears when.

Answer (score -1):

Android fragments have their own life cycle very similar to an android activity.
[image: See the image]

**onAttach()** The fragment instance is associated with an activity instance.In this method you get the reference of the activity which called the fragment.

**onCreate()** The system calls this method when creating the fragment.

**onCreateView()** The system calls this callback when it's time for the fragment to draw its user interface for the first time.

**onStart()** This method is called once the fragment gets visible.

**onDestroyView()** Fragment view will destroy after call this method

See this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm) for better understanding of life cycle.

Comment: Some parts of this answer are misleading. onStart() doesn't necessarily mean "the fragment is visible". To test; add a fragment to stack with `FragmenManager.add()` then pop back with back button `onStart()` will not be called.